# Pandas Full Name Split into First , Middle and Last Names

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe with a fullnames field, I want to change the logic so that the First and Last name will have all the first and last word and the rest will go into the middle name field.

Note: The full name can contain two words in that case middle name will be null and there may be also extra spaces between the names.

Current Logic:

```
fullnames = "Walter John  Ross Schmidt"
first, middle, *last = name.split()
print("First = {first}".format(first=first))
print("Middle = {middle}".format(middle=middle))
print("Last = {last}".format(last=" ".join(last)))

Output :

First = Walter
Middle = John
Last = Ross Schmidt
```

Expected Output :

```
FirstName = Walter
Middle = John Ross
Last = Schmidt
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use negative indexing to get the last item in the list for the last name and also use a slice to get all but the first and last for the middle name:

```
fullnames = "Walter John  Ross Schmidt"
first = fullnames.split()[0]
last = fullnames.split()[-1]
middle = " ".join(fullnames.split()[1:-1])
print("First = {first}".format(first=first))
print("Middle = {middle}".format(middle=middle))
print("Last = {last}".format(last=last))
```

PS if you are working with a data frame you can use:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'fullnames':['Walter John  Ross Schmidt']})
df = df.assign(**{
    'first': df['fullnames'].str.split().str[0],
    'middle': df['fullnames'].str.split().str[1:-1].str.join(' '),
    'last': df['fullnames'].str.split().str[-1]
})
```

Output:

```
   fullnames                  first   middle     last
0  Walter John  Ross Schmidt  Walter  John Ross  Schmidt
```

Comment: Hi @Zach , this is the best answer so far, so upvoted and accepted. Thanks Legend.

Answer (score 2):

You can use capture groups in the regex passed to `str.extract()`, which will let you do this in a single operation:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    "name": [
        "Walter John  Ross Schmidt",
        "John Quincy Adams"
    ]
})

rx = re.compile(r'^(\w+)\s+(.*?)\s+(\w+)$')

df[['first', 'middle', 'last']] = df['name'].str.extract(pat=rx, expand=True)
```

This gives you:

```
    name                        first   middle      last
0   Walter John Ross Schmidt    Walter  John Ross   Schmidt
1   John   Quincy Adams         John    Quincy      Adams
```

Comment: Hi @Mark thanks for your answer but the above gives Nan , when I have name with two words e.g. "Ash Ketchum"

Answer (score 1):

I would use `str.replace` and `str.extract` here:

```py
df["FirstName"] = df["FullName"].str.extract(r'^(\w+)')
df["Middle"] = df["FullName"].str.replace(r'^\w+\s+|\s+\w+$', '')
df["Last"] = df["FullName"].str.extract(r'(\w+)$')
```

Comment: Hi @Tim, thanks for replying. Always looking forward to your answers but this time, it does not work when I have only two words in my full name e.g. "Ash Ketchum" , it duplicates the Middle and Last Name.

Comment: @Ash ... and your sample data did not make mention that there would even be cases of no middle name being present.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following line instead.

```py
first, *middle, last = fullnames.split()
```